# merge query running very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am using Oracle DB and trying to issue a merge query by using spring jdbc temple.

Sample oracle query is as follows

```
 MERGE INTO table_name  b
     USING (select 'id','fid','somedata' from DUAL a
     ON (a.id = b.id and a.fid = b.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET col_name = 'some_val' where  lastUpdateTime > someTime
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (id,fid col_name)
     VALUES ('id','fid', 'some_val')
```

This query was running propery before but its running very very slow now(In minutes)

The table details : 
id,fid as composite primary key 
partitioned on record creationDate. 
No of records in table is  around 15 million

Why is the query performane so slow?

Comment: Intrigued by a PK supported by an index partitioned on a non-PK column. Didn't think that was possible -- are you sure?

Comment: @David Aldridge you can partision the table on no pk columns

Comment: Yep, but I read it to mean that the index is itself partitioned.

Comment: Have you runned the Oracle cost-based optimizer (CBO)? If don't, you can try running it before run the query. Its available in 11g and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

When it's running for minutes you should find an explanation using

```
select * from v$session_longops where time_remaining > 0
```